# Modify fields of not unique lines in text file

Tags: bash, sorting, unique

I'am working on a script that needs to get the duplicated lines from a single text file and change the value on the date field, but only the time of day field. The field  delimiter is TAB so ...

```
# cat enviando4
1414743351      2014-11-01 09:00:00
1414743351      2014-10-31 09:15:51
1414743351      2014-10-30 23:00:00
1414743351      2014-10-31 09:15:51
1414743351      2014-10-30 23:00:00
1414743351      2014-10-31 10:25:00
1414743351      2014-10-31 09:15:51
1414743351      2014-11-01 10:25:00
```

I sort the lines by date:

/bin/sort enviando4 -k2 -t $'\t' -o enviando4

```
# cat enviando4
1414743351      2014-10-30 23:00:00
1414743351      2014-10-30 23:00:00
1414743351      2014-10-31 09:15:51
1414743351      2014-10-31 09:15:51
1414743351      2014-10-31 09:15:51
1414743351      2014-10-31 10:25:00
1414743351      2014-11-01 09:00:00
1414743351      2014-11-01 10:25:00
```

Now I need to add  at least 4 minutes (never subtract) to any duplicated dates least one so I will have only unique dates. It'd look some thing like this:

```
# cat enviando4
1414743351      2014-10-30 23:04:00 --> add 4
1414743351      2014-10-30 23:00:00 --> no change
1414743351      2014-10-31 09:19:51 --> add 4
1414743351      2014-10-31 09:23:51 --> add 8
1414743351      2014-10-31 09:15:51 --> no change
1414743351      2014-10-31 10:25:00 --> unique, no change 
1414743351      2014-11-01 09:00:00 --> unique, no change
1414743351      2014-11-01 10:25:00 --> unique, no change
```

and verify those changes did not make new duplicated values.
I am stuck on this.
Thank you.

Comment: If you reversed the sort order then you will need to add 4 minutes to the *last* duplicated line - much easier to do in something like awk - hold one line in buffer, check for change of key, munge the held line, ...

Answer (score 0):

Your task is not that difficult. Bash has fantastic date manipulation utilities. What you need to do is `sort the original` list, then `read each line` of the sorted file, `compare the date/time to the previous` date time and using a counter, increase the duplicate time by a `counter * 4min` offset, and `write the new date/time to your output file.` There are many ways to handle the time adjustment. The easiest is to convert the date/time string to seconds since epoch. Then simply add the offset to the duplicate time and covert it back to the date/time format desired.

The following example shows one approach to doing this. There are several operations that can be combined, but I have left the offset calculation separate to make it more readable. The script takes an input file as the first argument (I have it set by default to `dat/env4.dat` **for my testing**, set as you please). The script then sorts to a temp file, reads the temp file, makes the time adjustment to duplicates, then writes the output to `inputfile.out`, deleting the temp file before exiting. Let me know if you have any questions:

```
#!/bin/bash

ifn="${1:-dat/env4.dat}"            # set input filename (ifn) and validate

[ -r "$ifn" ] || {
    printf "\n  Error: input file not readable. Usage: %s [<filename> (dat/env4.dat)]\n\n" "${0//*\//}" >&2
    exit 1
}

## initialize variables
tfn="/tmp/${ifn//*\//}.tmp"         # set temp filename  (tfn)
ofn="${ifn}.out"                    # set output filename (ofn)
:> "$ofn"                           # truncate output file
pdate=0                             # initialize prior date
cnt=0                               # counter variable
tos=240                             # time offset in seconds (4 min.)
tse=0                               # time since epoch in seconds

sort "$ifn" > "$tfn"                # sort input file into temp file & validate

[ -r "$tfn" ] || {
    printf "\n  Error: sort failed to produce a tmp file or tmp file not readable\n\n" >&2
    exit 1
}

## read temp file into index/idate and add 4 min to each successive duplicate
while read -r index idate || [ -n "$idate" ]; do

    if [ "$pdate" = "$idate" ]; then
        tse=$(date -d "$idate" +%s) # get time since epoch for idate
        cnt=$((cnt+1))              # increase counter
        nos=$((cnt*tos))            # set new time offset (not Nitrous Oxide)
        ntm=$((tse+nos))            # set new time including offset
        # write new time to output
        printf "%s\t%s\n" "$index" "$(date -d "@${ntm}" +"%F %T" )" >> "$ofn"
    else
        cnt=0; nos=0                # reset counter and new time offset
        # write output unchanged
        printf "%s\t%s\n" "$index" "$idate" >> "$ofn"
    fi

    pdate="$idate"                  # save current date/time as prior date/time

done <"$tfn"

[ -r "$tfn" ] && rm "$tfn"          # remove temp file
```

**input file:**

```
$ cat dat/env4.dat
1414743351      2014-11-01 09:00:00
1414743351      2014-10-31 09:15:51
1414743351      2014-10-30 23:00:00
1414743351      2014-10-31 09:15:51
1414743351      2014-10-30 23:00:00
1414743351      2014-10-31 10:25:00
1414743351      2014-10-31 09:15:51
1414743351      2014-11-01 10:25:00
```

**output file:**

```
$ cat dat/env4.dat.out
1414743351      2014-10-30 23:00:00
1414743351      2014-10-30 23:04:00
1414743351      2014-10-31 09:15:51
1414743351      2014-10-31 09:19:51
1414743351      2014-10-31 09:23:51
1414743351      2014-10-31 10:25:00
1414743351      2014-11-01 09:00:00
1414743351      2014-11-01 10:25:00
```

**Note:** if you would like to flip the duplicates so that the larger offset time appears first, you should can operate on the output file. Doing it within the `offset while loop` would overly complicate the logic for the purpose of this question. The basic approach if you want to include the additional code in the `offset while loop` is to store the prior date and any matching dates in an array and then offset the array date/time values and write them out in reverse order. Unset the array each time a new date/time is encountered.

---

**Addendum Including E-mail and Adjust Field**

If you are interested in adding to the output to include an `e-mail` at the beginning, and then including a `time adjustment` in between the `date portion` and `time portion` of the `new date field`, you can do so relatively easily by simply adding the email at the beginning and then splitting the new string returned by `date` into the `date part` and `time part` and inserting `00:0n:00` between the two in your output. Whether you use `printf` or `echo` makes no difference. `printf` is far more flexible, but there are times where `echo` provides advantages as well.

**Note:** in the code below, I form the `00:0n:000` (with `n` being `4, 8, etc..` assuming only 2 duplicates. If there are 3 or more, you will have to handle that to adjust the logic to form `00:nn:00` if the adjusted time is greater than `8 minutes` (e.g. `12, 16, 20, ...` for the `3rd, 4th, 5th, ...` duplicate).

Let me know if you have further question.

```
## beginning part of script unchanged
# tse=0                               # time since epoch in seconds
email="mi@email.com"                # email to output
adjtm=4                             # simple value to provide adjustment in 00:04:00, etc.

sort "$ifn" > "$tfn"                # sort input file into temp file & validate

[ -r "$tfn" ] || {
    printf "\n  Error: sort failed to produce a tmp file or tmp file not readable\n\n" >&2
    exit 1
}

## read temp file into index/idate and add 4 min to each successive duplicate
while read -r index idate || [ -n "$idate" ]; do

    if [ "$pdate" = "$idate" ]; then
        tse=$(date -d "$idate" +%s) # get time since epoch for idate
        cnt=$((cnt+1))              # increase counter
        adj=$((cnt*adjtm))          # compute 4, 8, ... for 00:0n:00 output
        nos=$((cnt*tos))            # set new time offset (not Nitrous Oxide)
        ntm=$((tse+nos))            # set new time including offset
        ndt="$(date -d "@${ntm}" +"%F %T" )"  # new date/time value
        nd1=${ndt% *}               # date portion (first field) of ntd
        nd2=${ndt#* }               # time portion (second filed) of ntd
        ncmb="$nd1 00:0${adj}:00 $nd2" # new combined "date 00:0n:00 time" string
        # write new time to output
        printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$email" "$index" "$ncmb" >> "$ofn"
    else
        cnt=0; nos=0                # reset counter and new time offset
        nd1=${idate% *}             # date portion (first field) of idate
        nd2=${idate#* }             # time portion (second filed) of idate
        ncmb="$nd1 00:00:00 $nd2"   # new combined "date 00:00:00 time" string (no adj)
        # write output unchanged
        printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$email" "$index" "$ncmb" >> "$ofn"
    fi

    pdate="$idate"                  # save current date as prior date

done <"$tfn"

[ -r "$tfn" ] && rm "$tfn"          # remove temp file
```

**output file: (with same input)**

```
$ bash env4-2.sh
mi@email.com    1414743351      2014-10-30 00:00:00 23:00:00
mi@email.com    1414743351      2014-10-30 00:04:00 23:04:00
mi@email.com    1414743351      2014-10-31 00:00:00 09:15:51
mi@email.com    1414743351      2014-10-31 00:04:00 09:19:51
mi@email.com    1414743351      2014-10-31 00:08:00 09:23:51
mi@email.com    1414743351      2014-10-31 00:00:00 10:25:00
mi@email.com    1414743351      2014-11-01 00:00:00 09:00:00
mi@email.com    1414743351      2014-11-01 00:00:00 10:25:00
```

Comment: Thank you for the script :-). Big help for me. I've been for a while trying to adapt the script to my needs and I am having some problems with this bit: printf "%s\t%s\n" "$index" "$(date -d "@${ntm}" +"%F %T" )" >> "$ofn" I am using some more fields than two. This is the output:             mi@email.com    186808  2014-11-02 00:04:00     12:06:00 . The old date is 2014-11-02 12:06:00 and I'm getting 00:04:00 and 12:006:00 instead of 2014-11-02 12:10:00. I can post my code if necessary.

Comment: No need to post. All changes will simply be to the controlled by the `read` and then a concatenation after read. Before I write an addemdum, confirm that basically we just need to not consider `00:04:00` and consider the date string to be `2014-11-02 12:06:00` for purpose of checking duplicates and adjusting time in your total string of `mi@email.com 186808 2014-11-02 00:04:00 12:06:00`

Comment: Yes. My initial string is: pg      1358    mi@email.com    186808  2014-11-02 12:06:00     0       2 and it should look at the end: pg      1358    mi@email.com    186808  2014-11-02 12:10:00     0       2   The line I'm using to write it back is: printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$SISTEMA" "$MENSAXE_ID" "$EMAIL" "$NUMERO_DESTINATARIOS" "$(/bin/date -d "@${NTM}" +"%F %T" )" "$ESTADO" "$GRUPO" >> pendientes.sorted but I get: pg      1358    mi@email.com    186808  2014-11-02 00:04:00     12:06:00        0       2     Your script works really nice along. Thx

Comment: I think I understand. Look over the output. (I adjust both the `00:0n:00` and the actual time. If you don't need the actual time adjusted and just need the `00:0n:00` that just requires removing code :)

Comment: no, I don't need the actual time. My question is, if the date is  2014-11-02 23:58:00 when the script add those 4 minutes the date will be 2014-11-03 00:02:00. Anyway it will change to 2014-11-03?. I use to do /bin/date +"%Y-%m-%d %T" --date "now +$ADD_MINUTES mins" to do this things but I can't make it work cos can't replace the now with a variable. Thanks

Comment: Well I think I found out where the problem may be. The IDATE variable that gets the  read -r command does not read the full date, but only the date part, no the houre part, so this is what I get: 2014-11-02
2014-11-02, etc and it should be 2014-11-02 12:06:00, etc. Is there any other way to red those lines knowing that the field separator is TAB and date and houre are separated by a space? thanks.

Comment: No -- idate reads the date and time. It reads everything from the index number to end of line. And yes, it will roll the date forward if `23:58` it rolls to `00:02 the next day`. One thing that might help you is to make a copy of the script (a test copy) and then put `echo` or `printf` statements after each line you have a question about. Example, after the read: `echo "idate: $idate"`. If you want to see every variable in the program while it runs, just as `set -x` below `#!/bin/bash` Also, don't forget to accept the answer, unless you get a better one :)